# Action does not receive the form's value

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

How to get a value that is sent by a form in jsp.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not sending `Name` back to the controller.for sending values back to the action all you need to send them as form fields where as in your case you are just displaying them but not sending them back.

One solution is to store the name as a hidden field like

```
 <s:form action="AddProduct" >
        <tr><td>
                <label for="name">Name:${Product.name}</label>
                <s:hidden name="name" value="%{Product.name}"/>
        </td></tr>
     <s:submit/>
 </s:form>
```

Make sure you should have name property in your action class or if you have a bean in your action class who has name property than the name of hidden field shd be `beanName.name`

Comment: I used your code but the output is name is :  (null is removed but nothing has been shown)

Comment: you used the same code what i written? since there is a typo in the value ;), i just corrected it

Comment: no it does not work, is that because I have the form in <sx:div>?

Comment: @EmeEmertana: It's always better to provide complete information in your post

Comment: the code has not changed I used the code in the question which did not work then amend it as you askes me but still does not work is there any other part of code that you need me to share?